# Name change not shown in Sharepoint

Tags: user, import, ad

Our SharePoint 2007 farm imports user info from AD daily. We have found a problem with one user (there may be more).

This user has changed her surname - it was changed on AD and imported to sharepoint. When handling her name on one site, it shows the name correctly with the new surname. However, on another site the name shows with old surname.

Comment: is the User profile synchronization done successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the user profile sync is showing to be done on schedule.
As I mentioned some of the sites show the new name correctly but one or two others do not (they show the old surname).
So it appears to be some kind of sync between the indexing server and some sites.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your profile is synced with the AD, only the profile is updated... not the 'User info list" (one per site collection) that holds display information for each user. The site where the name is OK may be a site the user has browsed for the first time recently, while the other one was an "old-visited" site.

You can find more info at [User Information List not sync'd with User Profile database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/user-information-list-not-syncd-with-user-profile-database), or other external links like (http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2009/10/01/user-profile-information-not-updated-on-site-collection-s-people-and-group.aspx.