# some users pictures aren't showing up in the userlist

Tags: user, picture

I have a strange situation where most of users pictures showing up in the _catalogs/users/detail.aspx list. However there are hand full of users picture aren't showing up and including title and other information. I made sure their profile pictures are loaded (user profile db) and all the information (title, phone, dept, etc). I ran this stsadm -o sync command and it ran successfully but no result. Any idea what else I need to do?

Comment: Update: Set-SPUser -Identity $user -SyncFromAD only populated name field and title, dept, photo is still missing. Anyone ???

Comment: Just went through this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/user-information-list-not-syncd-with-user-profile-database and did a full sync. I am not sure what would be the next step to sync User List with Profile DB.

Comment: This link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5922a5bb-a58a-4d24-9100-28484e67eec7/question-about-user-profile-synchronization-user-information-list-and-sharepoint-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious also provides good explanations on UPS DB and UIL are not related.

Comment: I am going to give this script (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Sync-SharePoint-User-2c59052a) a try and post the result here.